# How to name set of edges connecting set of nodes with one node in a oriented graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a directed graph $G$ , with some set of nodes $R$.

For this set of nodes $r \in R$, I ask whether all nodes link to a given node $n$ not belonging to $R$. That is I ask if from each of nodes $r \in R$ there exists an edge $e(r,n)$ linking node of our path with node $n$.

1) How can we name such relation between set of nodes $R$ and node $n$.

2) In case of multigraph, where there can be more than one edge $e(r,n)$ How can we enumerate through such .. 'connections' , 'cuts' ?

What rings a bell form me is a:

- clique
- cycle
- cut

but I cannot find a proper definitons for this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: a star? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarGraph.html